# Read Error with new harddrive

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive, bios

I put in a new HDD into my stationary computer and have tried to install Windows 7, Fedora 21 and Ubuntu 14.10.
Windows 7 didn't install at all, when I created the partition and clicked "Format" it did some work for a while and then presented me an error (I believe it was 0X80070057).
Fedora 21 installed beautifully but presented me with either "Read error" or the Grub menu which allowed me to boot into Fedora, **once**.
Ubuntu 14.10 installed but it froze upon reboot, when it said to terminate all remaining processes (here I did a hard shutdown and rebooted). I never got into the Grub menu with Ubuntu.

I should mention that the HDD is a Seagate 1TB, if I swap the cables to a much older Maxtor HDD with Windows 7 Home Premium on it there are no problems booting. Also the BIOS acts strangely with the Seagate drive, sometimes it doesn't add the drive in the boot list but still recognizes it afterwards if I boot a GNU/Linux installer from USB and sometimes it is stuck in BIOS so I have to reboot again.

Edit: I have done a SMART check with smartctl, both short and long. No errors on the disk.

Comment: What was your partition type that you had created on your new Seagate HDD?? While installation did you find any strange behavior like taking too much time while installing or something else??

Comment: and Can you please put your PC's specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with Xen2050, it isn't clear if you mean you changed the cables as well or not.  And even if you used the same cables, the cables could be bad or stretched out.  certainly try other cables.  I love seagate but it could have been damaged in shipping.  One day I heard a brick hit my porch Newegg shipped a hard drive without so much as a bubble wrap bag around it, just thin plastic.  I gave them such a rant fest they didn't dare refuse to pay return shipping.  Your drive could just be bad.  It happens.

Or it could be that your computer refuses to recognize hard drives of that size.  depends how old the bios is.

Here's a test you can do.  While booted to a live boot CD, please open Disk Utility and if the seagate supports SMART see what it has to say about the drive health.  If it claims it is healthy (unlikely) or if it does not support SMART, you can ask that it perform diagnostic tests.

Comment: I used the same cables when swapping disks. Will try another SATA cable tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: The BIOS is from 2012, that's the latest version for my motherboard, ASUS P7P55D LE.

Comment: I have done tests with smartctl, do you mean that other tests can be done from a Live DVD?

Comment: good 'nuf for +1

Comment: Turns out swapping cables did the trick, thank you :)

Comment: @AndreasNilsson, As you've recently discovered, in reality you cannot necessarily trust any cable just because it appears to work with another device (historically that test was considered good enough).  There's another thing you will want to add to your geek arsenal which I've come to appreciate in nearly every aspect of repair.  It is a product which can apparently turn an apparently bad cable into a good cable with virtually no financial expense.  It is marketed as a "contact cleaner", but if you own a DVM you will find it has greater properties.  Look it up, CAIG DeOxit D100L.

Answer (score 0):

So what's your question?

You said you get errors, but *"if I swap the cables to a much older Maxtor HDD with Windows 7 Home Premium on it there are no problems booting."*

Soooooooooo... you've diagnosed and found bad cables? Or just a bad hard drive? If it's new then take it back, or use better cables if that works.